# Occurrence rate of positional TEV vs clubfoot

Tags: obstetrics, congenital, uterus

I have not seen any data on this, perhaps because there is no reliable way to diagnose TEV as positional. However, is there anything that demonstrates how many congenital TEV/Clubfoot cases are positional (due to uterine abnormalities or fetal positioning)?